# Aurelia - erro ao executar o comando npm run build:prod

Tags: front-end

Estou aprendendo o [aurelia](http://aurelia.io) (framework front-end) e baixei um projeto demo ([Aurelia_Full_Esnext_Webpack](http://coreui.io)) do site http://coreui.io/.

Estou executando o comando npm run build:prod, mas exibe erro no final do build.
O build de desenvolvimento rola perfeitamente. Alguém já teve o mesmo problema pra me ajudar? O erro tem haver com o UglifyJs.

Agradeço!

[image: erro aurelia]